# declare activity in manifest

Tags: android, android-activity

Try to give an action bar to my activity and even it out, this is not working.

My activity:

```
public class ValidacionMultiple extends SherlockActivity{

String title = "Test";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
   setContentView(R.layout.validacion_multiple);
   getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3d3d3d")));
   getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ticket_green);
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + title + "</font>"));
 }
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
08-04 17:28:13.877: E/AndroidRuntime(29969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 17:28:13.877: E/AndroidRuntime(29969): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.eventrid.scanner/com.google.zxing.client.android.ValidacionMultiple}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

However, if I declare my activity

```
<activity  
     android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ValidacionMultiple" 
     android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherkol" 
     android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Edit :

[image]

Comment: What's your application package? When you write .ActivityName you basically say that the class is in the same package as your application package. If that's not true try writing the fully qualified class path.

Comment: Try it with the name of the package where it is, with the name and the rough. "." and none work for me. I'm working with the library zxing.

Comment: Try exactly like this: "com.google.zxing.client.android.ValidacionMultiple"

Comment: I get the same error ...

Comment: Make sure you cleaned your project, if that doesn't work I'm out of ideas at the moment,

Comment: in the manifest com.google.zxing.client.android.ValidacionMultiple and clean and rebuild the proyect

Comment: Clean whole project, uninstall the application from my mobile but nothing works, I keep getting the same error. Edit my post, if some of that is making problems

Answer (score 0):

Well, after exhausting several possibilities, I went with the obvious and never thought. It is a library that zxing imported into my root project therefore was to declare the activity within the manifest. I had no idea the truth but was solved.